# Permanent connection across activity bound service

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, synchronization, ipc

Problem statement =>
I am trying to communicate between two apps, say App A(client side) and App B(server side). I am using AIDL based approach. It takes time to create connection between A and B, also the binding process is asynchronous and I need to immediately use the created connection after it gets binded. Something like this =>

```
final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            IStubbingInterfaceObject = IStubbingInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            IStubbingInterfaceObject = null;
        }
    };
// 
context.bindService(explicitIntent, serviceConnection, 0);
String answer = IStubbingInterfaceObject.callServiceInAppB();
```

Here since the bindService is asynchronous process, when the thread moves to next line there is no guarantee that binding is completed, and it actually fails stating "IStubbingInterfaceObject" is null.

---

The solutions that come to mind are

- Is it possible to bind App A itself with the service in App B so that I can use binding anywhere across the App A.
- Synchronize binding procedure, which i tried by using

```
context.bindService(explicitIntent, serviceConnection, 0);
while(IStubbingInterfaceObject == null)
String answer = IStubbingInterfaceObject.callServiceInAppB();
```

or any other possible solution that anyone can add.

Comment: "I need to immediately use the created connection after it gets binded" -- then your code for that belongs in `onServiceConnected()`. "when the thread moves to next line there is no guarantee that binding is completed, and it actually fails stating "IStubbingInterfaceObject" is null" -- correct. That is unavoidable. "Is it possible to bind App A itself with the service in App B so that I can use binding anywhere across the App A" -- you may want to edit your question and explain in greater detail what you mean by this.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to use it synchronously?

Comment: I want to use the response "answer" for futher processing

Comment: by binding App A with the service in App B, what is meant is to keep the created binding active even if the activity is changed.

Comment: "what is meant is to keep the created binding active even if the activity is changed" -- you are welcome to bind from some more stable object, such as a repository-style singleton. "is there a way to use it synchronously?" -- no.

Comment: Adding to CommonsWare, binding is inherently asynchronous. To make it synchronous, you would have to create a wrapper around the bind calls (e.g. `bindServiceSync()`). However, I would discourage doing so because binding is asynchronous on purpose. Especially if the client and server are in separate processes, binding could take >100ms which will block the main thread. If you need binding throughout the entire Activity lifecycle, then bind in onCreate and unbind in onDestroy. Either way, you will still have to handle scenarios where binding fails or calls to AIDL fail due to crashes.

Comment: Actually I want to reuse the created binding across actiivities or persist that binding somehow so that when I move from parent activity to child activity I don't have to create binding once more and reuse it in onCreate method of child activity.

This is an alternative approach I am considering.